# Angular md-dialog container div dosent disappear on Firefox

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

after clicking on any of `md-dialog` buttons (ok,cancel,create..) the dialog it self diaper but a `<div class="md-dialog-container"></div>` which is part of the default dialog code dose not diaper and act as a cover to the all web page, turning it unresponsive..

i have found this link https://github.com/angular/material/issues/3782 but the solution suggested doesn't seem to work..

any advice would by highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

i ended up using some basic js to solve this problem

js:

```
$scope.removeDialogContainer=function(){
            $('.md-dialog-container').addClass('display-none-md-dialog-container'); 
        };
```

css:

```
.display-none-md-dialog-container{
    display: none !important;
}
```

adding this code (`$scope.removeDialogContainer()`) to the relevant dialog buttons seems to work

in my opinion it's not the best solution, would have preferred a css or html solution, not using js..